Google Cloud TTS Phonemes do not sound as constructed
I'm working to replicate as closely as possible the terms "hello" and "thank you" as they are spoken in the Choctaw language ("yakoke" and "halito", respectively).
"yakoke" as pronounced in the Choctaw language can be heard on their dictionary page (direct to word: yakoke)
Ultimately, the intention is to use TTS over the telephone and this is important to them. Per this response, I can confirm the Google TTS demo doesn't support the <phoneme> tag. Thus, I turned to code to generate the output.
void Main()
{
  var builder = new TextToSpeechClientBuilder();
  builder.ApiKey = "<api key from Google TTS project>";
  var client = builder.Build();

  // The input to be synthesized, can be provided as text or SSML.
  var input = new SynthesisInput
  {
    Ssml = "<speak><phoneme alphabet=\"ipa\" ph=\"ˌjɑː.kɔː.ˈkiː\">dad</phoneme></speak>",
  };

  // Build the voice request.
  var voiceSelection = new VoiceSelectionParams
  {
    LanguageCode = "en-US",
    Name = "en-US-Wavenet-C",
  };

  // Specify the type of audio file.
  var audioConfig = new AudioConfig
  {
    AudioEncoding = AudioEncoding.Mp3
  };

  // Perform the text-to-speech request.
  var response = client.SynthesizeSpeech(input, voiceSelection, audioConfig);

  // Write the response to the output file.
  using (var output = File.Create(@"C:\Temp\yakoke.mp3"))
  {
    response.AudioContent.WriteTo(output);
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Audio content written to file \"yakoke.mp3\"");
}

This does generate output (what it generated for me), but it's incorrect in two ways.

The second syllable is supposed to sound as a long 'o' (as in boy). Based on the Supported phonemes and levels of stress for US English, the code ɔː should generate this sound. Instead I hear a repeat of the first vowel.
The stress markers do not affect the accent on any of the syllables. In the reference audio, it's clear to hear the last syllable receives the primary stress.

What am I missing here?
